# I''ve been having problems with the subscription process using my client

Tags: xmpp

Im using Jabber-Net API to make a GMail client. I've been having problems with the subscription process using my client as it always returning the "subscription=none" and "ask=none". When i subscribe a new user, it works fine but, subscribing/ unsubscribing users very frquently from roster makes the users stop to send subscription request with "to/ from/ both" or etc. 
I have discovered that, "CONTACT" always receives a packet like this:

```
<iq type="set">
    <query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster">
      <item
          jid="jabberuser@host"
          subscription="none"
          ask="none"/>
    </query>
  </iq>
```

Any prompt answer will be much appreciated..

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here, but the answer is probably in [XMPP IM, RFC 6121](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6121).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending a presence subscription?

```
<presence type='subscribe' to='jabberuser@host'/>
```